# rasa: training is too slow

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x

I have rtx 3090 gpu and i9 12th gen processor. my training is not too large as well and yet the training time is too long. When I begin the training phase it says 24 cores available but limiting to safe limit of only 8 cores. NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS not set.

Comment: I have come to know after some research this NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS is a tensorflow variable. how can i set this? anyone has any idea?

Comment: rasa interactive is also slow loading. I have tested multiple installations

Comment: Please put all your information in your question post and not down here in comments. Your post doesn't even contain a question at this point. See [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal add the `NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS` to your terminal.
You can do so by writing in your CLI:  `export NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS="24"` if you want to use all of them. This will work until you close your terminal. You can add it permanently to your terminal profile (.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc ...)
Regarding slow execution, that depends on your rasa config choices and the number of stories/rules.
Finally, you need to pass the param `use_gpu = True` in your config for TedPolicy t make it train TED faster.